# Derivation of the sun constant formula (using the elliptical orbit of the earth around the sun)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, physics, elliptic-functions

In a book, I've to read for a class at my university, they gave a formula that looks like:

$$\text{G}_\text{sc}\left(\text{n}\right)=1367\cdot\left(1+0.03\cos\left(\frac{360}{365}\cdot\text{n}\right)\right)\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\left[\text{W}/\text{m}^2\right]\tag1$$

Where $\text{n}$ is a day in a year.

That formula is called the sun constant formula, but I do not know where it comes from.

> Question: Can someone help me derive this formula?

---

**My work:**

I think that the energy flux is given by:

$$\text{G}=\mathcal{k}\cdot\text{T}^4\cdot\left(\frac{\text{R}}{\text{D}}\right)^2\tag2$$

Where $\mathcal{k}$ is the Boltzmann constant, $\text{T}$ is the surface temprature of the sun, $\text{R}$ is the radius of the sun and $\text{D}$ is the distance from the sun to the earth.

Now, for $\text{D}$ we know that is changes over a year because the earth makes a elliptical orbit around the sun.

Comment: By [Kepler's first law][1], the distance of the Earth from the Sun is given by
$$ R=\frac{p}{1+\varepsilon \cos\theta} $$
where $\varepsilon$ is the eccentricity of the orbit and $p$ is the semi-latus rectum.

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler's_laws_of_planetary_motion

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks first of all, but why does the formula I stated follow from Kepler's law??!

Comment: Let me know if my answer satisfies you.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I've a comment under your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us put a few things together. By Kepler's first law the distance of the Earth from the Sun is given by
$$ D(\theta) = \frac{p}{1+\varepsilon\cos\theta} $$
with $\varepsilon$ being the eccentricity of Earth's orbit, $p$ being the semi-latus rectum and $\theta$ being the angle perihelion-Sun-Earth. The way $\theta$ changes over time depends on Kepler's second law, giving that between day $0$ (Earth at the perihelion) and day $A$ (assuming the year has exactly $365$ days) the identity
$$ \frac{A}{365}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{p}{1+\varepsilon\cos\theta}\right)^2\,d\theta = \int_{0}^{\theta_A}\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{p}{1+\varepsilon\cos\theta}\right)^2\,d\theta$$
holds. That gives [Kepler's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler's_equation): in order to find $\theta$ at a given time of the year, we have to solve a trascendental equation (through Newton's method, for instance). However, since the orbit of the Earth has a low eccentricity, we may assume that the Earth has a constant angular speed with respect to the Sun, leading to $\theta_A = \frac{A}{365}\cdot 360^\circ$. The energy emitted by the Sun is proportional to $T^4$ by Boltzmann's law, hence the flux of such energy through a sphere with radius $D$ is proportional to $\frac{1}{D^2}$, i.e. to
$$ \left(1+\varepsilon \cos\theta\right)^2 = 1+ 2\varepsilon\cos\theta + \varepsilon^2 \cos^2\theta $$
where the $\varepsilon^2\cos^2\theta$ term can be neglected by the same reason as before: $\varepsilon$ is pretty small.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you stated: "we have to solve a trascendental equation" but which equation are you talking about? And how does this derives my sun constant formula?

Comment: The trascendental equation I was talking about is exactly Kepler's equation (have a look at the link). I was remarking that your formula is just an approximation, since it assumes that the angular speed of the Earth is constant ($\theta_A\sim A$) but also that the orbit has a non-zero eccentricity. Long story short, that $0.03$ is just twice the eccentricity of Earth's orbit.

Comment: Yes, if you compute such integrals, you end up with Kepler's equation, giving the true relation between $A$ and $\theta_A$, that is not $\theta_A = \frac{A}{365}\cdot 360^{\circ}.$

Comment: So when I assume nothing, I need to solve: $$ \frac{A}{\text{n}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{p}{1+\varepsilon\cos\theta}\right)^2\,d\theta = \int_{0}^{\theta_A}\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{p}{1+\varepsilon\cos\theta}\right)^2\,d\theta$$ Where $\text{n}$ is the number of days in a year. And when I solve that equation for $\theta_\text{A}$ what does that give me (what is $\theta_\text{A}$ is that my $\text{G}_\text{sc}$)?

Comment: A horrible thing, that for practical purposes we assume to be $\frac{A}{365}\cdot 360^{\circ}$, according to $\varepsilon\approx 0$ implying constant angular speed.

Comment: $\theta_A$ is the angle $\theta$ (defined in my answer) at day $A$.

Comment: Oke, I understand. So what will my formula $\text{G}_\text{sc}$ looks like using your information?

Comment: Again, long story short: Boltzmann gives that $G$ is proportional to $\frac{1}{D^2}$. Kepler gives that $\frac{1}{D}$ is proportional to $1+\varepsilon\cos\theta$. $\varepsilon$ is small, hence $G$ is approximately proportional to $1+2\varepsilon\cos\theta$, with $\theta\approx\frac{360^\circ}{365}\cdot n$, assuming $n$ days are passed from the solstice of winter (Earth at the perihelion).

Comment: Oke, so I get: $$\text{G}=\mathcal{k}\cdot\text{T}^4\cdot\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(\theta_\text{A}\right)\right)^2}$$ And that $\theta_\text{A}$ I need to solve out of the integrals?!

Comment: No-oh. If $G = k T^4 R^2\cdot \frac{1}{D^2}$ and $D=\frac{p}{1+\varepsilon\cos\theta}$, what is $G$?

Comment: Sorry I mean: $$\text{G}=\mathcal{k}\cdot\text{T}^4\cdot\frac{\text{R}^2}{\left(\frac{\text{p}}{1+\epsilon\cos\left(\theta_\text{A}\right)}\right)^2}$$ Is this correct? Also the $\theta_\text{A}$?

Comment: All right, that is $\frac{k T^4 R^2}{p^2}\cdot\left(1+2\varepsilon\cos\theta_A\right)$ by neglecting the $\varepsilon^2$ term. Then, by assuming the Earth has a constant angular speed, $\theta_A = \frac{360^\circ}{365}\cdot n$.

Comment: Yes I understand, so my equation I stated after the sorry I mean is correct?!

Comment: Yes it is.$\phantom{}$

Comment: This answer is partially incorrect, not enough so as to be worthy of a downvote. The problem is that $\frac 1 {(1+k\cos x)^2}$ has an antiderivative in the elementary functions. This is not the right equation. While the antiderivative is a bit ugly, it does exist. Keplerian orbits on the other hand are notoriously transcendental.

Comment: I do not understand your point. What is incorrect? That trigonometric integral is doable, sure, but it is its inverse function that really matters. Otherwise, how do you write the relation between time and angle?

Comment: And anyway, in Op's first formula something is clearly approximated: the dependence time-angle is assumed to be linear and at the same time the eccentricity is considered as non zero.